# Related to plotting histogram with specific bins

Tags: python, arrays, histogram, bins

I am trying to plot a histogram with following bins:

```
plt.hist(abs_mag1, bins=[50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 1050, 1150, 1250])
```

But as I run the code I found out these bins are an array in the output. I didn't get any errors but also I didn't get a histogram with expected bins.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]. What do you expect as output? A figure in a window?  A PNG file?